# How to plot a vglm/propodds regression?

Tags: r, plot, regression

Update:
When I tried "dput" to show some of my data this is all I was able to see was a long series of 0s and 1s an then:

```
  label = "CURRENT JOB STATUS- 1", class = c("labelled", 
"integer"))), .Names = c("is.controlrp", "is.lowrp", "is.somerp", 
"is.highrp", "is.substantialrp", "is.ignorerp", "Risk_Pct", "PCT_Stocks_MF_1", 
"is.native", "is.male", "rp", "rp2", "is.lowrp.1", "is.controlrp.1", 
"is.somerp.1", "is.highrp.1", "is.substantial2", "is.ignorerp.1", 
"psm1", "psm2", "noStocks", "is.control2", "is.low2", "is.some2", 
"is.high2", "is.substantial2.1", "is.ignore2", "age2", "agenew", 
"tw", "is.controlW", "is.debt", "is.lowW", "is.medW", "is.highW", 
"sme", "is.controlSME", "is.lowSME", "oh", "ms", "cjs"), row.names = c(NA, 
-16000L), class = "data.frame")
```

If this helps at all, here's "head":

```
   > head(dummydata2)
      is.controlrp is.lowrp is.somerp is.highrp is.substantialrp is.ignorerp Risk_Pct PCT_Stocks_MF_1
    1            1        1         1         0                1           1        7              50
    2            1        1         1         1                0           1       10              NA
    3            1        1         1         0                1           1        8              40
    4            1        1         1         0                1           1        8              40
    5            1        1         1         0                1           1        8              40
    6            1        1         0         1                1           1        5             998
      is.native is.male          rp rp2 is.lowrp.1 is.controlrp.1 is.somerp.1 is.highrp.1
    1         0       1        high   3          1              1           1           0
    2         0       0 substantial   4          1              1           1           1
    3         0       1        high   3          1              1           1           0
    4         0       1        high   3          1              1           1           0
    5         0       1        high   3          1              1           1           0
    6         0       1        some   2          1              1           0           1
      is.substantial2 is.ignorerp.1 psm1   psm2 noStocks is.control2 is.low2 is.some2 is.high2
    1               1             1    3   high        1           1       1        1        0
    2            <NA>             1   NA   <NA>       NA        <NA>    <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
    3               1             1    2   some        1           1       1        0        1
    4               1             1    2   some        1           1       1        0        1
    5               1             1    2   some        1           1       1        0        1
    6               1             1    5 ignore        1           1       1        1        1
      is.substantial2.1 is.ignore2 age2 agenew tw is.controlW is.debt is.lowW is.medW is.highW sme
    1                 1          1    2      1  4           1       1       1       1        0  NA
    2              <NA>       <NA>    3      1  1           1       0       1       1        1  NA
    3                 1          1    3      1 NA          NA      NA      NA      NA       NA  NA
    4                 1          1    3      1 NA          NA      NA      NA      NA       NA  NA
    5                 1          1    3      1 NA          NA      NA      NA      NA       NA  NA
    6                 1          0    3      1  4           1       1       1       1        0   4
      is.controlSME is.lowSME oh ms cjs
    1            NA      <NA>  0  1   1
    2            NA      <NA>  1  1   1
    3            NA      <NA>  0  0   0
    4            NA      <NA>  0  0   0
    5            NA      <NA>  0  0   0
    6             1         1  0  1   0
```

Hi I'd like some help plotting the following regression in "r":

```
fit1_usesrp <-vglm(rp ~ is.native + is.male + oh + cjs + age2 + tw ,propodds, data = dummydata
```

Through this regression I am interested in finding if immigration status is a determinant of risk preferences. "rp" in the regression is a categorical variable that measures respondent's willingness to take risk (no risk tolerance, low risk tolerance, etc.). "is.native" is a dummy variable for immigration status (0 = native, 1 = immigrant). oh, cjs, and age2 are all dummy variables for factors that may affect risk preferences. "tw" is for total wealth and I used the actual raw values for wealth instead of trying to turn this into a dummy variable.

the output for this regression is:

```
Call:
vglm(formula = rp ~ is.native + is.male + oh + cjs + age2 + tw, 
    family = propodds, data = dummydata2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept):1 (Intercept):2 (Intercept):3 (Intercept):4 (Intercept):5     is.native       is.male 
 2.796024e+00 -4.948484e-01 -5.055242e-01 -6.460196e-01 -2.545089e+00 -7.381110e-02  1.509080e-01 
           oh           cjs          age2            tw 
-2.070633e-02  3.643551e-03  7.149891e-02 -3.092727e-06 

Degrees of Freedom: 52000 Total; 51989 Residual
Residual deviance: 24705.39 
Log-likelihood: -12352.69 
> summary(fit1_usesrp)

Call:
vglm(formula = rp ~ is.native + is.male + oh + cjs + age2 + tw, 
    family = propodds, data = dummydata2)

Pearson residuals:
                    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
logit(P[Y>=2])  -5.0292  0.1305  0.2830  0.2989  0.5201
logit(P[Y>=3])  -0.6676 -0.5986 -0.5517  0.5911 14.8594
logit(P[Y>=4]) -13.1696 -0.5270 -0.4856  0.6051  3.0437
logit(P[Y>=5])  -4.0121 -0.4082 -0.3802  1.0345  1.2412
logit(P[Y>=6])  -0.6133 -0.5764 -0.1601 -0.1548  3.5492

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept):1  2.796e+00  6.689e-02  41.803  < 2e-16 ***
(Intercept):2 -4.948e-01  5.352e-02  -9.246  < 2e-16 ***
(Intercept):3 -5.055e-01  5.353e-02  -9.444  < 2e-16 ***
(Intercept):4 -6.460e-01  5.368e-02 -12.035  < 2e-16 ***
(Intercept):5 -2.545e+00  6.113e-02 -41.635  < 2e-16 ***
is.native     -7.381e-02  6.224e-02  -1.186   0.2357    
is.male        1.509e-01  3.764e-02   4.010 6.08e-05 ***
oh            -2.071e-02  4.747e-02  -0.436   0.6627    
cjs            3.644e-03  4.365e-02   0.083   0.9335    
age2           7.150e-02  2.449e-02   2.920   0.0035 ** 
tw            -3.093e-06  1.479e-06  -2.092   0.0365 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Number of linear predictors:  5 

Names of linear predictors: 
logit(P[Y>=2]), logit(P[Y>=3]), logit(P[Y>=4]), logit(P[Y>=5]), logit(P[Y>=6])

Dispersion Parameter for cumulative family:   1

Residual deviance: 24705.39 on 51989 degrees of freedom

Log-likelihood: -12352.69 on 51989 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations: 4 

Exponentiated coefficients:
is.native   is.male        oh       cjs      age2        tw 
0.9288471 1.1628897 0.9795066 1.0036502 1.0741170 0.9999969
```

Comment: How do you plot a regression that has more than 3 dimensions? I'm only aware of plotting diagnostics for these kinds of models.

Comment: Can you tell me more about plotting diagnostics? I just want some form of visual representation for my regression instead of only this raw data

Comment: If you are looking to visualize the accuracy or fit of your model, I might be able to help.  But as I said in my first comment, visualizing a high dimensional regression is... impossible?

Comment: Well I guess that explains why I couldn't find a way to plot this regression. Yes, if you could explain how to visualize the accuracy or fit of the model I would appreciate that.

Comment: No problem, I'll be able to in a bit.

Comment: Can you post some of your data?  Try `dput(your_data)`.